# Excel VBA "Expected: end of statement" error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a formula in Excel using VBA. The purpose of this formula is to eliminate the "-", "+", "#" and " " in the string present in cell D2.

```
Range("P2").Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"-",""),"+",""),"#","")," ","")"
```

When I paste this formula in cell P2, it works as intended. However, when using the above code, the compile error "Expected: end of statement" is shown.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: you need to use  cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(D2, "-", "")

Comment: @yass It appears that double quotes have to be escaped in VBA. See the answer I posted to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error, it seems that the double quotes have to be doubled, like so:

```
Range("P2").Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,""-"",""""),""+"",""""),""#"",""""),"" "","""")"
```